# Modal Is Deleting The First Row In The Table Incorrectly. How Do I get the right ID associated with my DELETE button?

Tags: javascript, django, modal-dialog

I've been at this all day.  I've researched it and the docs are a bit scarce.  I do recognize that I am getting the first ID at the top of the table because the IDs are all the same.  I don't know how to get the "right" ID when I'm deleting the row.  The modal is popping..and the delete works...it's just the wrong record gets deleted...

HTML

```
 {% for notify in notify_list %}
   <tr style="vertical-align:top">
      <td class="hide">
            <div id="myModaldelete" class="modaldelete">
              <div class="modal-content-delete">
                <span class="closedelete"></span>
                <img class="logo4" src="/static/images/threecircles.svg">
                <p>Delete Request?</p>
                <button type="button" class="button165" id="yesBtndelete" value="{{ notify.id }}">Yes</button>
                <button type="button" class="button160" id="noBtndelete">No</button>
              </div>
            </div>
            <button type="button" class="button114">
            <div class="txtalgn114"><h2 class="txtalgn114a">Delete</h2></div></button>
          </td>
          </tr>
          {% endfor %}
```

My Javascript...

```
   // Get the modal
   var modaldelete = document.getElementById("myModaldelete");

   // Get the button that opens the modal
   var btndelete = document.getElementById("myBtndelete");

   // Get the button that opens the modal
   var nobtndelete = document.getElementById("noBtndelete");

   // Get the <span> element that closes the modal
   var span = document.getElementsByClassName("closedelete")[0];

   // When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
   span.onclick = function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     modaldelete.style.display = "none";
   }

   // When the user clicks on the No button, close the modal
   nobtndelete.onclick = function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     modaldelete.style.display = "none";
   }

   // When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
   window.onclick = function(event) {
     if (event.target == modaldelete ) {
       modaldelete.style.display = "none";
     }
   }

   $(document).on('click', '.button114', function(e) { // note the e, thats the event

       modaldelete.style.display = "block";

   });

   $(document).on('click', '.button165', function(e) { // note the e, thats the event

      var id = $(this).val();          
      document.location.href = "/url/" + id;

   });
```

I've read about maybe adding the ID to the ID name so that it's unique as a possible solution...I just can't figure out how to get it to work...Thanks in advance for any thoughts....I'm not using BootStrap on purpose...Just for the record...

Answer (score 1):

You might just be opening the wrong modal, since you're opening the modal with:

```
modaldelete = document.getElementById("myModaldelete");
```

but wouldn't there be more than one of these, because you're looping through and creating the modals in the:

```
 {% for notify in notify_list %}
```

You'd probably want to do something like:

```
 {% set index = 0 %}
 {% for notify in notify_list %}
   <tr style="vertical-align:top">
      <td class="hide">
            <div id="myModaldelete{{index}}" class="modaldelete">
...
  {% index++ %}
  {% endfor %}
```

which would give the modals different ids, and then you'd need to reference which modal to open with the button like:

```
<button type="button" class="button114" onclick="openModal({{index}})">
        <div class="txtalgn114"><h2 class="txtalgn114a">Delete</h2></div></button>
```

and inside openModal():

```
function openModal(index) {
  var modaldelete = document.getElementById("myModaldelete" + index);
  modaldelete.style.display = "block";
}
```

Hopefully that works!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I played with this theory as well...but I can't add an index...I also tried an ID...and the concept worked...but the result is still the same.  It's still just deleting the first record in the table, not the one that I necessarily want.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you are doing a mistake by giving `id` to repeated HTML elements. You can avoid such by giving that `id` value as `class` instead. Then, you can give your row ID in a `data` attribute:

```
<button type="button" class="myBtndelete" data-id="{{ notify.id }}">Yes</button>
<button type="button" class="noBtndelete">No</button>
```

Now, you can get all your `myBtndelete` buttons by using `getElementByClassName` instead.

Also, you can get the ID value on click using:

```
$(document).on('click', '.myBtndelete', function(e) { 
    var id = $(this).data('id')
    document.location.href = "/url/" + id; 
});
```

**Another way:**
You can replace your `button` elements with `a` elements in order to give them `href` attribute on the fly without having to handle the click explicitly using JavaScript, but you have to handle the styling of the anchor `a` elements to have the button look and feel like giving them some Bootstrap classes:

```
<a href="/some-url/{{notify.id}}" class="btn btn-primary myBtndelete">Yes</a>
```

Comment: Thank you for the response.  I tried your suggestions and I'm still just getting the first record.  It's as if the person below suggests, it's always opening the first modal...Still investigating.

Comment: you can do the second I have mentioned, then inspect element in your browser and check what is the rendered href in each of `a` element

Comment: Thanks again but it still is only finding the record at the top of the table no matter which suggestion I have tried to use the result is the same.

Comment: I've inspected it...and the table appears as you suggest it would...with different IDs...the problem is when the modal is presented.  It only detects the first record...the ID is not getting properly passed to the modal.  That much I'm sure of.

Answer (score 0):

Ok...After about a day or two of playing with this concept...I figured it out...I was missing a few things...Most importantly the back and forth with the Javascript and the ID value...I had to add the following Javascript logic...I moved the modal out of my loop and added a hidden input to get the ID value. Thanks to all who helped me piece this one together. It was complicated. For me anyway.

```
   $('.button114').on('click', function (event) {
     modaldelete[0].style.display = "block";
     var id = $(this).data('id');
     document.getElementById("modal-input-value").value = id;
   });

   $('.button165').on('click', function (event) {
     // Get the hidden input element
     var hiddenInput = document.getElementById("modal-input-value");
     // Get the value of the hidden input
     var id = hiddenInput.value;
     document.location.href = "/url/" + id;
   });

  <div id="myModaldelete{{ notify.id }}" class="modaldelete">
    <div class="modal-content-delete">
      <span class="closedelete"></span>
      <img class="logo4" src="/static/images/threecircles.svg">
      <p>Delete Request?</p>
       <input type="hidden" id="modal-input-value">
      <button type="button" class="button165">Yes</button>
      <button type="button" class="button160" id="noBtndelete">No</button>
    </div>
  </div>

{% for notify in notify_list %}
  <tr style="vertical-align:top">
{% if user.userprofile.eDirector_queue_delete_confirm == "Yes" %}
<td class="hide">
  <button type="button" class="button114" data-id="{{ notify.id }}">
  <div class="txtalgn114"><h2 class="txtalgn114a">Delete</h2></div></button>
</td>
{% endif &}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I am glad you figured it out. I believe that the answers below helped you with a way or another, if so, please vote up the helpful answers. Thanks.